# python list not showing full elements

Tags: python, list, neural-network, caffe

I'm inserting images into Decaf, and want to extract features from 6,7,8th layers. 6th and 7th are supposed to be 4096-dimensions, and 8th is supposed to be 1000.

I'm assuming that the generated output functions like a list, and want to record each element in a separate text file as follows:

```
def intoDecaf(image):
    img = misc.imread(image)
    fname = str(image)
    fname = fname.replace('.jpg','')
    print fname
    scores = net.classify(img,center_only=True)
    feat6 = net.feature('fc6_cudanet_out')
    feat7 = net.feature('fc7_cudanet_out')
    feat8 = net.feature('fc8_cudanet_out')

    f6name = fname+'-f6.txt'
    f7name = fname+'-f7.txt'
    f8name = fname+'-f8.txt'

    f6 = open(f6name,'w')
    f7 = open(f7name,'w')
    f8 = open(f8name,'w')

    for f in feat6:
        f6.write(str(f))
        f6.write('\t')
   # and the same for f7 and f8
```

The f8 file correctly has 1000 files, but f6 and f7 text files have something like the following:

```
[ -1.63451958  -8.0507412   -1.09678674 ...,  11.38702393   1.99127924
   4.76321936]
```

The dots in the middle are literally like that. What happend to all the numbers? Do those dots signify something? some kind of abridgement?
Is this something that has to do with decaf or python?

Comment: Maybe whatever `f` is, has a special implementation of `__str__` which "helpfully" shortens its representation using an ellipsis. I wonder what would happen if you tried `f6.write(f)` or `f6.write(repr(f))`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `feat6` is a NumPy array.
If so, instead of

```
f6name = fname+'-f6.txt'
f6 = open(f6name,'w')
for f in feat6:
    f6.write(str(f))
    f6.write('\t')
f6.close()
```

use

```
import numpy as np

f6name = fname+'-f6.txt'
np.savetxt(f6name, feat6, delimiter='\t')
```

This won't include the brackets (`[` and `]`), but that is usually more desireable as it makes parsing the data easier.

---

The `str` representation of NumPy arrays includes ellipses when the number of elements in the array exceed `threshold` which by default NumPy sets to 1000. You can change this by [setting `threshold` to some higher number](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.set_printoptions.html):

```
import numpy as np
np.set_printoptions(threshold=10**6)
```

With this change, `str(f)` would return a stringified version of `f` without ellipses as long as `f.size` is less than 10**6.

While this explains why you are seeing ellipses, I don't recommend using `np.set_printoptions` here since `np.savetxt` solves your problem more simply.

Comment: this worked beautifully! thanx! I'll accept this in an hour :)